# knockout custom mapping of child arrays

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout.js and am trying to create a complex object based on a work history.

I'm currently able to pass in the data
An employee has positions which have projects which have experiences, etc etc.
While I'm able to pass in the data and populate the child objects, I believe what want to do is build up my child objects manually so I can attach methods and computedObservables. I'm just not sure how do wire up my other objects.
Do I write a for each loop or is there some spiffy knockout magic to make this simpler?

any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Namespace.viewModel = function (model) {
              console.log('initViewCalled');         

              var memberVM = {
                  Id: ko.observable(model.Id),
                  FName: ko.observable(model.FName),
                  LName: ko.observable(model.LName),
                  Positions: ko.observableArray(model.Positions),
              };              
            // computed goodness goes here
              memberVM.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
                  return this.FName() + ' ' +  this.LName();
          }, memberVM);// methods
          this.addPosition = function () {
              this.Positions.push({MemberId:this.MemberId });
          } .bind(this);
          return memberVM;
      };

      Namespace.position = function (model) {
          var positionVM = {
              EndDate: ko.observable(model.EndDate),
              Description: ko.observable(model.Description),
              HoursPerWeek: ko.observable(model.HoursPerWeek),
              HourlyRate: ko.observable(model.HourlyRate),
              MaxDate: ko.observable(model.MaxDate),
              MinDate: ko.observable(model.MinDate),
              MemberId: ko.observable(model.Id),
              Name: ko.observable(model.Name),
              PositionId: ko.observable(model.Id),
              Summary: ko.observable(model.Summary),
              SalaryEnd: ko.observable(model.SalaryEnd),
              SalaryStart: ko.observable(model.SalaryStart),
              StartDate: ko.observable(model.StartDate),
              Title: ko.observable(model.Title),
              Projects: ko.observableArray(model.Projects), // automapped...
          };

          this.addProject = function () {
              this.Projects.push({ MemberId: this.MemberId });
          } .bind(this);

          return positionVM;
      };

      Namespace.project = function(model) {
          var projectVM = {
              EndDate: ko.observable(model.EndDate),
              Description: ko.observable(model.Description),
              MemberId: ko.observable(model.Id),
              Name: ko.observable(model.Name),
              PositionId: ko.observable(model.Id),
              StartDate: ko.observable(model.StartDate),
              Experiences: ko.observableArray(model.Experiences) // auto-mapped
          };

           this.addExperience = function () {
                  this.Experiences.push("New Experience");
                }.bind(this);

          return projectVM;
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming in already structured, consider using the [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin to convert everything to `observables`/`observableArrays`.

I think this is what you are trying to do.

Using the `mappingOptions` you can add in computed observables, if you'd like.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the response. I've got the data mapped via the mappingOptions. However, what I'm looking to do is add behaviors to these child-grandchildren objects, such as add, delete and also make certain child behaviors observable as well. My (limited) understanding of Knockout is that the items in an observableArray are themselves not observable.  if there is a way to use the mappingOptions + inject custom behavior that would be great and save me a whole lot of typing, do you know where I could see an example?